# Validate JTextField value so that it starts with "RA" then has 8 digits

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField` where in the user has to input the data.  Its value has to always start with `RA` and must have exactly 8 digits after it.  So, its length will be 10 always. for e.g., `RA12345678`.

How do I do this in Java?

I tried using `MaskFormatter` and `JFormattedTextField`  but, did not achieve the results.  I need to validate the input with length together.

Comment: When do you want it to be verified? After an action, or while the user is typing?

Comment: So why force the use to enter the RA? Why not just display a label with "RA", then you can create a JFormattedTextField that will only accept 8 numeric digits.

Comment: Try using [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) instead, with [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) and [more examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a `JSpinner` for this, and simply prefix `RA` to the number.  E.G.

#### Image

[image]

#### Typical Output

```
RA8007006
```

#### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CaptureRA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String prefix = "RA";
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(4));
                gui.add(new JLabel(prefix));
                SpinnerModel ints = new SpinnerNumberModel(
                        1000000,1000000,99999999,1);
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(ints);
                gui.add(spinner);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
                System.out.println(prefix + ints.getValue());
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1416631, I agree with the prefix part, since I originally suggested it ;) I'm not sure about the spinner part. To me a spinner is used when you have reason to increment a number by a predetermined value to obtain another reasonable value within a predetermined range. Also, the visual display is different from the printed display. I don't think the 8 digits represent an actual number but more likely represent a part/product id of some kind, so displaying the thousands separator doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: *"since I originally suggested it"* Yeah, I thought that was a good suggestion.  If it is 'fixed' why ever let the user touch it?