# Is there a way in Java to set a JTextField's position to be at the start of the text?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

```
private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setText("10000000000");
```

If the `JTextField` is small, which mine are, it'll show the last so many characters.  In this case, that would be something like "00000" if only five characters can be shown given the area of the text field.  I want to set the position automatically to the start of the `JTextField` once I press a separate `JButton`.  So, in this case, I would want "10000" to show.

I have a list of multiple `JTextFields` and a `JButton` that does calculations on them and finds things like the total, then prints that total in another `JTextField`, and you only see the last part of the total which can get confusing if you don't realize it's showing the end of the text instead of showing it from the beginning.

I looked through all the "`.set***`" methods and didn't see any option to do this.

Comment: `private JTextField textField = new JTextField(); textField.setText("10000000000");` possibly better `private JSpinner orderSize = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(..));` E.G. as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16271173/418556).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`JTextField#setCaretPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition(int))

```
textField.setCaretPosition(0);
```

You could also highlight the text using...

```
textField.setCaretPosition(textField.getText().length());
textField.moveCaretPosition(0);
```

But `JTextField#selectAll` would be simpler...

Depending on your needs, you can also "suggest" the preferred number of columns that the field should display, for example...

```
private JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
```

or

```
textField.setColumns(15);
```

This will encourage some layout managers to ensure that the field is sized to a more appropriate size based on the fields needs